# Python code in T-SQL environment gives "access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions" Error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017, python

Help on the following please.

I have this code Python Code

```
  import requests
  r = requests.get("https://www.google.com")
  r.status_code
  print(r.status_code)
  print("Python Rawks!!!!!!")
```

which runs fine in command line mode and returns the 200 status code.

The same code in T-SQL query window fails with OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

```
execute sp_execute_external_script@language = N'Python',@script = N'
          import requests
          r = requests.get("https://www.google.com")
          r.status_code
          print(r.status_code)
          print("Python Rawks!!!!!!")
'
```

> Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
>   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 83, in create_connection    raise err
>   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_connection    sock.connect(sa)
>
> OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
>   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Answer (score 1):

Open the Windows Firewall and look for a rule called "**Block network access for R local user accounts in SQL Server instance MSSQLSERVER**" (assuming you have a default instance).  This Firewall rule blocks network access from SQL Server external scripts.  You can disable the rule if you want to allow network access.

Comment: Or you can disable the firewall for a moment to see if that solves the issue, then start looking for the particular rule. Worked for me.